# If you maintain multiple bikes, what's better in the long-run, audible or visual FD tuning?

Tags: shimano, derailleur-front

There are two schools for tuning a front derailleur.

- The **visual school**, described in Shimano Dealer's Manual, is to tighten the hi/lo screws by *inspecting* the gap between cage and chain, and seeking a minimal gap at either extreme. Once mastered, the process can be done in a few minutes.
- The **audible school**, [carefully](https://youtu.be/ZNG7g83lI-s) presented by Calvin Jones at Park Tools, involves an in-depth analysis of how a false hi/lo limit can be set. Jones describes how to eliminate potentially false limit settings using an intricate system for the limit screws, cable tautness, and barrel adjustment—a system that relies on *listening* for chain-cage rub. Even after using this method a dozen times, it's still hard to learn every detail by heart. It remains necessary to go back to the notes (or tediously watching the video again).

In my experience the **audible school** is superior. It creates enough of an overlap between chainrings that I can skip trimming altogether.

By contrast the "official" **visual school** is considerably simpler, but trimming is essential.

Maintaining multiple bikes makes choosing between the two schools damning.

- If I use the **visual school**, then I need to go back to the Dealer's Manual for each bike.
- If I use the **audible school**, then I need to consult the videos.

This problem must already be solved by the pros. If you maintain multiple bikes, what's better in the long-run, audible or visual FD tuning?

Comment: And then there is third school, when the barrel adjuster does not work (perhaps I did something wrong when unpacking the bike, or I unscrewed it too much so that the threads disconnected, but it has never worked). Connect the cable with some tension and hope for the best.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I had trouble with my Sora FD for about a month. I was unable to tune it well, until I found (https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/67779/48599) that the barrel adjuster was not adjusting anything. It was slipping. A careful touch of grease solved that problem.

Comment: What's wrong with using BOTH?